# How to take or consider only limited text when user entered in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can anyone help me on a small requirement. I did much R&D but could not find my solution. The problem is, in SQL, how to take a limited text from whole text when user enters ?
ex: If user entered john@abc.com, I want only "john" & "@abc.com" has to be replaced with NULL in SQL.
Can anyone help me on this please.

Comment: What do you mean by *"@abc.com" has to be replaced with NULL*. Do you want to remove `@abc.com`

Comment: Yes. I would like to remove @abc.com

Comment: select   left ( string , (charindex('@',string)-1) )

Comment: @Indian - I think he meant an empty string: `""`

Comment: `Stuff(string , Charindex('@', string ), Len(string ), '')` or `LEFT(string, Charindex('@', string)-1)`

Comment: OFFTOPIC: why you wrote IDIOT your last name. IDIOTS doest ask questions. they are always in fear of being judged

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @User nvarchar(50) = 'jon.doe@abc.com'

SELECT DISTINCT
         STUFF(@User, CHARINDEX('@', @User), len(@User ), '') AS [User]
```

Is your question only for EmailID's or for other scenario's as well??

Answer (score 1):

When the third parameter in SUBSTRING or the second parameter in LEFT is negative, you will get an error.

With this syntax you don't risking getting an error when the *@* doesn't exists, it will return nothing if there is no *@*:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('john@abc.com', 0, charindex('@','john@abc.com'))
```

A different way of handling this issue using LEFT. This will return the whole text if there is no *@* in the text:

```
SELECT LEFT('john@abc.com', charindex('@','john@abc.com' + '@') - 1)
```

Result:

```
john
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the optimal solution will be to store emails as they are and when you show just extract name part only

```
declare @email varchar(100)
    set @email='john@email.com'
    select substring(@email,1,charindex('@',@email)-1) as name_only
```

Answer (score 0):

try the below code, this will give you the name part and replace everything else with NULL -

```
create table #email (emailid varchar(20))
insert into #email
select 'john@gmail.com' union
select 'nojohn@yahoo.co.in'
select * from #email
select  substring(emailid,1,patindex('%@%',emailid)-1),
replace(emailid,substring(emailid,patindex('%@%',emailid)+1,(patindex('%.%',emailid)-1)-patindex('%@%',emailid)),NULL) 
from #email
```